# if else not working in opencart 3 twig file

Tags: twig, opencart-3

i'm trying to integrate the following code in opencart 3,but i don't know why my code id not executing?i'm new to twig.Please help me to fix this issue.

```
{% for product in products %}
 {{ product.total}}  
 {% set my_total = product.total|replace({'AED': '', ',': ''}) %}
 {{ my_total }}
  {% endfor %}
{% if my_total >= 500.00 %}
{% set randomPassword = [] %}
{% set alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' %}
{% set numbers = '0123456789' %}
{% for i in 1..10 %}
{% set randomCharacter = random(alpha ~ alpha|upper ~ numbers ~ '-_') %}
{% set randomPassword = randomPassword|merge([randomCharacter]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set randomPassword = randomPassword|join %}
{{ order_id }}{{ randomPassword }}
{% else %}
(text)
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So.. What is the expected output?

Comment: @DarkBee, sir, i want to check the amount, if amount is greater than 500 it will send a random code otherwise text.But i'm stuck with this part.This will not send any mails.This condition blocks the mail part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined inside a `for`-loop are only known inside such loop.
As you are trying to access `my_total` outside the loop u'd need to define it outside the loop, e.g.

```html
{% set my_total = 0 %} {# <--- outside the loop #}

{% for product in products %}
    {% set my_total = my_total + product.total|replace({'AED': '', ',': ''}) %}
{% endfor %}

{% if my_total >= 500.00 %} {# <--- still accessible #}

    {% set randomPassword = [] %}
    {% set alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' %}
    {% set numbers = '0123456789' %}

    {% for i in 1..10 %}
        {% set randomCharacter = random(alpha ~ alpha|upper ~ numbers ~ '-_') %}
        {% set randomPassword = randomPassword|merge([randomCharacter]) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% set randomPassword = randomPassword|join %}
    {{ order_id }}{{ randomPassword }}
{% else %}
    (text)
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/muaaqi)

---

note: You should enable debug mode in order to see twig errors, when running your code you clearly get the following error

> Variable "my_total" does not exist.

Comment: thanks for your support, but still my forms are not submitting.

Comment: Well.. Did you enable the debug? Did you check your error logs? Code above clearly works as seen in the demo

Comment: @ DarkBee, Thanks its working.I'm getting error "Notice: Undefined index: flat ",datsy the forms are not submitting.

Comment: Sorry,Could you please tell me how can i avoid notice error of flat rate.

Comment: That is a whole different question and is not related to your initial question. Please post a new question with your controller code